# Is there a way to put a delay in the execution between two statements in a function in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a "game" in the unity console. In this game I have the console display what I want to say to the player, but because the console isn't meant for things like this it's becoming crowded with text. In my function where I tell the player I got their answer right, I'm also restarting the game. But this leads to all the dialogue loading at once, which doesn't give the player a chance to see my response to the previous game.

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("I'm a genius :)");
            StartGame();
        }
```

I was hoping to either have the game delay the StartGame(); function (which contains all the dialogue for the start of a new game) after the Debug.Log function executes. Or if possible, have the player press a button to execute the new game.

Comment: You probably want to read about Coroutines and see how they work. You can easily wait in those without breaking anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not familiar enough with scripting in unity. but based on this [answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/796881/c-how-can-i-let-something-happen-after-a-small-del.html) form unity forum

You can do it with coroutines in any MonoBehaviour:

```
 IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

     // Code to execute after the delay
 }
```

You can call it with, for example, StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(10));

Note that it will execute asynchronous so put everything that has to wait for it to be done, inside the coroutine.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)